# Symfony2 entity manager get not working all the time

Tags: php, symfony

I found a strange issue in symfony2 (maybe is not strange and i did a mistake somewhere):

- i'm trying to call an entity manager method that i defined in the entity class:

  ```
  //Entity/organisation.php
  /**
   * @return string
   */
  public function getApiUrl(){
      return $this->api_url;
  }
  ```

  and i don't always get a return value for the same object
- the call is made from a controller method:

  ```
  private function addApiLog($organisationId, $callType, $eventInfo){

  $em = $this->getEntityManager();

  $organisation = $em->find('\WebAgenda\Entity\Organisation', $organisationId);
  if (null === $organisation) {
      die();
  }

  $apiUrl = $organisation->getApiUrl();
  $apiKey = $organisation->getApiKey();

  $fc = fopen("debug_api_log.txt", "a");
  fwrite($fc, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$callType." - ".$organisationId." - ".$organisation->getName()." - ".$apiUrl."\n");
  fclose($fc);

  if(trim($apiUrl)!='' && $apiUrl!='-'){
  ```
- the 'addApiLog()' methos is called from different methods depending on the action and even though the organisationId that is passed to it is the same and i get the organisation object, sometimes the $organisation->getApiUrl() method doesn't return anything and the $organisation->getName(), always return the correct value: http://screencast.com/t/HQ2NuNfWSG9

What am I missing? Why i don't get values?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to use the repository class, like this :$organisation= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundle:Organisation')->find($organisationId);

Comment: are you sure `api_url` is correctly mapped and youve not forgotton the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$em = $this->getEntityManager();`

With this `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`

And then use your repository

```
$myRepo = $em->getRepository('NamespaceMyBundle:Organisation');
$organisation = $myRepo->find($organisationId);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't work in my application. First if i use $this->getDoctrine() i get "Fatal error:  Call to undefined method", and if i leave $em = $this->getEntityManager() and try the $em->getRepository('WebAgenda:Organisation') i get "Unknown Entity namespace alias 'WebAgenda'" ... and i tried all the possible namespaces that i have in the project related to organisation

Comment: If getDoctrine() is not defined then i think it's because you don't extend base symfony Controller class, all your controllers should extend  Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller, if you want to use the methods it provides

Comment: well the application was made to act like a API server and the controllers are extending an ApiBaseController that extends an ApiControllerProvider that extends a silex controller: ControllerProviderInterface .... but it works like this fine for all other actions, and it's strange that the call for the same search with the same id sometimes works and sometimes does not ...

Answer (score 0):

You said the `addApiLog()` method is called from different methods depending on the action.

Maybe not all your methods have access to the `Context` ?